# Get full image URL while exporting product in opnecart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

While exporting product data to excel from opencart I get only half URL of Image. For example, **"//catalog/New_SG/EW/sg-reliant-xtreme-english-willow-cricket-bat-size-6-30010731.jpg"**
Whereas I need
**"https://www.whitedotsports.com/image///catalog/New_SG/EW/sg-reliant-xtreme-english-willow-cricket-bat-size-6-30010731.jpg"**
For some purpose, I need full URL in excel export.
Please Guide how to Fix.

Comment: Why don't you just use the `CONCAT` feature in Excel and add on your site's URL?